# Question about fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha_j=2\cos(2j\pi/7),$ $\beta_j=2\sin(2j\pi/7)$ for $j = 1,$ $2,$ and $3$ where  $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ are the roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+x^2-2x-1$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

If $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ be a splitting field for $f(x)$
and the field  $L=\mathbb{Q}(\beta_1)$   contains $K, \beta_2$ and $\beta_3$.  Then:

a) show that there is an automorphism $\sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ such that $\sigma(\beta_j)=-\beta_j$ for $j\in\left\{1,2,3\right\}$

b) Determine $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: It would have been better,  much better iin fact, to have kept the first version. You had shown your work, so I would have upvoted it. Why did you delete it? The chanches of no one noticing that the same question is reposted are next to none :-). May be as a new user you didn't know how keenly some of us follow their favorite tags :-)

Comment: This is the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535647/question-about-fields), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534105/determination-of-subgroups-of-a-galois-group) under different user name.

Comment: they told me to write my attempt on the question instead of writing it in the comments

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533363/

Comment: Yeah, so they did. Thanks for complying, well done. That was all well. So why delete? The downvote might have become reversed. Anyway, let's stick to this version now.

Comment: It would be better to unify all your accounts and not to pose all questions several times. Then people would have more confidence in you, and would help you more.